# TinyMCE get form content without using submit button

Tags: forms, tinymce

I'm trying to put TinyMCE on my website.  I figured out how to get it to show up, but I'm lost on how to process the content.  In their example, they just have a link that references the top of the page and clicking on it somehow magically causes their dump.php script to execute.  I don't understand what's going on here.  Here is the link:

http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/basic.php

The "Submit" button at the bottom is really a link in a span element with href="#". The form action is dump.php. I want to know how they configured this to run without an actual submit button.  Any help in understanding this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

To Get Content From Tinymce You Can Use GetContent Method of Currently ActiveEditor Instance

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
```

method is used to getting Content .. to Set The Content

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent("I Want Text To Be in Tinymce");
```

to find a perticular element in tinymce get body and find element

```
var body = tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody();
$(body).find("#elem_id")
```

to get a full html

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getDoc().documentElement.innerHTML
```

hope that helps ..

Comment: I knew about these methods before, but I use PHP and I'm not sure how to pass info from javascript to PHP.  I really want to know how they are kicking off their PHP script when their button is not a button.

Comment: they are using links on on links click .. href having javascript  method which is executed

Answer (score 0):

Since I use PHP, I found this which is also useful:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:How-to_implement_TinyMCE_in_PHP